# Sinister allusions

Tags: etymology

I find it fascinating that 95% of the people I ask have no idea what *to drink the kool aid* is actually referring to (the tragedy at Jonestown).

Can y'all think of any other fun words or phrases with a similarly disturbing origin?

Comment: Hi Andy, you could ask this on ELL

Comment: @JoeBlow This is not by any stretch of the imagination an ELL question. It is asking about expressions that derive from gruesome references that are no longer widely known to native English speakers. Not ELL.

Comment: This is a really fun question but unfortunately also explicitly off-topic (list question). I'll abstain from voting myself, but I expect it will be closed shortly :(

Comment: "over a barrel" always makes me grimace.  "The metaphor is probably a reference to a prisoner being strapped over a barrel and flogged."  http://www.wordorigins.org/index.php/site/comments/over_a_barrel/

Answer (score 1):

Is this sufficiently sinister? "[Oh the humanity!](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/24129/oh-the-humanity)" (Hindenburg)

Reference:
https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/24129/oh-the-humanity

Answer (score 1):

A 'rule of thumb' originates from a law that said a man was allowed to beat his wife with a stick, so long as it was no thicker than his thumb.

I have remembered this since a history class in secondary school, though I have long forgotten the man (may have been a monarch or politician) who passed the law.

Comment: Just searched for the origin, and it seems that what I was told about it may be more myth than reality - http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/rule-of-thumb.html